# Issue in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a written a query to get values from one column in a table and represent them in two columns in data grid view based on where clause. Following is the query,

```
Select ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachineDescription AS "Machine Name",
    case when (ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001'  AND ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001')
    then ReadingValue
    end as [Last Day Meter Reading],
    case when (ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001'  AND ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT002')
    then ReadingValue
    end as [Current Day Meter Reading]
    from ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails
    INNER JOIN ElectricityMachinePanelDetails on ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachinePanelID = ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.MachinePanelID
    INNER JOIN ReadingTypesDetails ON ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.ReadingTypeID = ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID 
    WHERE ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001' AND ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'
```

Based on Reading type ID the values of columns changes.. for a example

if i use **ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT002'**

```
Machine Name           Last Day Meter Reading    Current Day Meter Reading                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Transformer 01           NULL                               60.000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Transformer 02           NULL                               60.000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Transformer 03           NULL                               80.000000
```

if i use **ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'**

```
Machine Name           Last Day Meter Reading    Current Day Meter Reading                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Transformer 01           52.000000                  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Transformer 02           55.000000                  NULL                     
Transformer 03           70.000000                  NULL
```

**Always one column is showing as NULL ** .. Can some one help me with this??

Comment: Remove "AND ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'" from where condition and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select  ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachineDescription AS "Machine Name",
        case when (ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001') then ReadingValue
        end as [Last Day Meter Reading],
        case when (ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT002') then ReadingValue
        end as [Current Day Meter Reading]
from ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails
INNER JOIN ElectricityMachinePanelDetails on ElectricityMachinePanelDetails.MachinePanelID = ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.MachinePanelID
INNER JOIN ReadingTypesDetails ON ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails.ReadingTypeID = ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID 
WHERE ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001'
```

Comment: After removing ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001' condition from where clause it gives values in both columns but machines are repeadted

Comment: Yes, It will be because there will be multiple records in ElectricityDailyMeterReadingDetails table for one MachinePanelID.

Comment: Is there no way to remove multiple values of machines in SQL? like distinct?

Comment: For that you need to add grouping on machine, but for one machine there will be multiple reading records, so which reading record you want to take (from multiple) for each machine ?

Answer (score 1):

```
case when (ReadingCategoryID = 'RC001'  AND ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT002')

This will never evaluate to "true", as long as you are selecting rows...

WHERE ... ReadingTypesDetails.ReadingTypeID = 'RT001'
```

Comment: I want to bring them in to one row. Like

Comment: Does it requires another ‘Case When’ to the query or is there any way. Appreciate you help